# Why is the icon of my dynamic button behind the text?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html and css. I finished workin on a "reveal button" tutorial and now wanted to change it according to my needs.

The button shows an icon at first. When hovering the text should appear.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: snow;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 25px;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: 1.35em;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* CONTAINER */

.container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.left_side {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1/ span 1;
  background-color: teal;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right_side {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1/ span 1;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* BUTTONS */

.cc-rockmenu {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #E4DFDF;
  color: green;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon {
  float: right;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52px;
  background: #9A9A9C;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon:hover .rolling {
  width: 312px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling i.fa {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 0px 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling p {
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Reveal Text Effect On Hover Button Tutorials</title>
  <meta name="description" content="In this tutorial, You will see how we can create reveal text effect on hover button or an icon." />
  <meta name="author" content="Codeconvey" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="revel.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Reveal-Buttons</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right_side">
      <div class="cc-rockmenu">
        <div class="rolling">
          <figure class="rolling_icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></figure>
          <span>Karte</span>
          <p>Parameter für Karte festlegen</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="cc-rockmenu">
        <div class="rolling">
          <figure class="rolling_icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">&nbsp;</i></figure>
          <span>Hintergrundkarten</span>
          <p>Wählen Sie die Hintergrundkarte!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="left_side"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My Problem: What ever I try the text always appears in front of the Icon and it's background. How can I change this?

I don't want to float the icon on the left side - that is the only solution so far.

Thank you very very much for your help and I hope the question is not too obvious.

Best
Felix

Answer (score -1):

add position relative to this for z-index to work.

```
  .cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon {
  float: right;
  position: relative; /*I have added it here*/
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52px;
  background: #9A9A9C;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: you have got to use a position property for z-index to work so if you ever use z-index you should remember to use position: fixed; position: relative; or position absolute; - without any of these then the z-index property will not work.

Comment: Great! Thank you Paul Maximus! I thought I only can Unterstützungseinsatz "position: relative" in combination with an offset like a { 
  position: relative; 
  top: -.9em; 
  left: -1.2em; 
}
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Felix, why have you removed the my answer, it was my answer that worked? DaMaGeX has stolen what others have said.